# Animation Sprite

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I want to create a 2D sprite that mimic the provided image:

http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/069/Purple2/v4/e6/0d/73/e60d73a8-6d78-64c2-dd59-9aabb54c7837/mzl.ujapwanw.320x480-75.jpg

and create different face expressions as provided sprites to unity3d in order to create an android application has multiple face expressions with those sprites... so my question... is what exactly the software I might use through out this process ??
Please, let me know the simplest step-by-step procedures, as I am in my first steps in computer graphics.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: be more specific,... you do not know how to encode or show sprites or how to paint image like that ... btw that image is not a sprite (unless the blue is not background)... what language and gfx api ?

Answer (score 0):

Image manipulation is what you are looking for. To modify the current image you have and generate other facial expressions from it, you need to be very good at math. Image manipulation is not a basic stuff and I hope you are not new to programming.

Now that you understand that, you need **OpenCV** to be able to do this. You need to make a wrapper for it in c#. You can get the already made wrapper [here].[1](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-opencv-for-unity.277080/) https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088  .It works on Windows,Mac, Android and iOS and will save you time. Its NOT free but the price is worth it compare to the time you will spend building the wrappers for all platforms.

Once you get this, you can start learning **OpenCV** from the following link.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/

http://shervinemami.info/openCV.html

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html

If you the Unity plugin I mentioned, you can ask the [author of the plugin](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-opencv-for-unity.277080/) to help you out if you are tuck.